# Подключение crystalreport к солюшену

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystalreport

Здравствуйте. В проекте используется crystalreport. Но у меня в visualstudio он не установлен. И поэтому вылетает ошибка.
Вот строки из wb.config для crystalreport:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

Вылетает ошибка на 1 строчке. Вот текст ошибки:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Ставлю для солюшена из нугета, пакет: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
И тогда вылетает уже вот такая вот ошибка:

> 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Почему ему не нравится такой референс? Я что то не то поставил? Как решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Референс не нравится, потому что версия не совпадает. Сделайте что б версия в Reference-подключеном к проэкту = версия физически в bin= версия в web.config = версия на паблике.

Comment: @nick_n_a А где найти версию референса? Там при установке написано v.1.0.0 что то вроде того. Но я думаю это немного не та версия.

Comment: Правой клавишой на dll, пункт свойства, закладка версия. Ещё можно удалить из assembly - и среда сама скажет добавьте такуюто строчку в web.config assembly c правильной версией

Comment: на данный момент у меня вырезаны все строки что я привёл в вопросе. И проставлены 3 пакета для кристал. Engine, web и shared. И не на что не ругается. Просто запускается и всё.

Comment: @nick_n_a а так что не знаю почему у меня не подсказывает с какой версией нужно добавить.

Comment: @nick_n_a и кстати тыкаю на dll. Нет свойств почему то.

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил скрин в вопрос.

Comment: @nick_n_a это и есть солюшен эксплорер.

Comment: В ms explorer в винде на dll-ке тыкнуть (не в vs)

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил скрин в вопрос. Оно? Если да то всё равно ошибка. Вот строка в конфиге. `<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.0.99, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>`

Comment: А текст ошибки обновился (версия там другая)? Вы точно везде версию выровняли?

Comment: @nick_n_a в веб конфиге, а где то ещё нужно? Да ошибка обновилась.

Comment: Самый первый коментарий. Референс удалить, подключить ту версию которая "правильная" в Референс.

Comment: @nick_n_a удалил референс который в бин добавился автоматом с версией 1. что то там. Тыкаю add reference та вообще нечего подобного про crystal report нет. Установил вроде правильно из нугета скрин в вопросе.

Comment: @nick_n_a попробовал физически скопировать в папку бин dll-ки из папки пакейдж где они были. Не помогло.

Comment: @nick_n_a в чём может быть проблема?